# PHP ini change local value

Tags: php, session, memcached, couchbase

I just set up PHP 5.5 with [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS). I am also running [Couchbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchbase_Server) to handle [Memcached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) sessions. I have one server running fine. The other keeps trying to save PHP sessions locally. I am not sure why. The PHP configuration has `session.save_handler=memcached` and `session.save_path="cb.path:11211"`.

The [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) page still lists the temporary session path as the "local" option and the handler to files, but `get_session_save_path()` returns the Couchbase URL.

How do I find where the local value is being set?

Comment: Memcache server is running? Host/port is correct?

Comment: couchbase is running

Comment: Why not run Couchbase on a separate node(s) so you can grow it if you need to and then use the Couchbase PHP 2.0 SDK? That is how you will get the best performance/features out of Couchbase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File */etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf* had *php_value* declarations overwriting the local variable.

```
#php_value session.save_handler "files"
#php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session”
```

This solution is a variant of this Stack Overflow answer: *[What is the difference between local value and master value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520744/what-is-the-difference-between-local-value-and-master-value/19520851#19520851)*

When in doubt, use:

```
grep -lR 'php_value' /etc/
```

Comment: hey there. You could flesh out your answer, at least clearly explain what line you set. You can then accept your own answer, you have the right to do that, so your question won't stay there as unanswered forever....

Comment: You definitely answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can set the runtime configuration using *ini_set()* or call through a *.htaccess* file.

1. Using a runtime configuration

   ```
    ini_set("session.save_path", "/var/lib/php/session");
   ```
2. Using a *.htaccess* file.

   ```
    php_value session.save_path  "/var/lib/php/session”
   ```

Comment: Some strange quote character: `”`. Does that actually work?