# I have to face session issue

Tags: php, session

I have to face session problem in my new server.

Session not working properly for [this link](http://brahmanparivar.com/session/)

I have refreshed page not show session and then again refresh page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> then session show.

So please tell me this is a server issue or coding issue ??

have a coding issue than solution me any one.

visit link to see phpinfo() : http://brahmanparivar.com/phpinfo.php

**index.php and display.php**

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>PHP session</title>
       </head>
       <body>       
           <? if(isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ){ 
                echo $_SESSION['name'];
           } else{
           echo "not have a Session";
       } ?>
       <br><br>
    <a href="index.php">home</a> <a href="display.php">display</a> <a href="set.php">set Session</a> <a href="logout.php">Session Out</a>
       </body>
    </html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
   if(isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ){
      session_destroy();
   }else{
       echo "not have a Session";
   }
?>
<br><br>
<a href="index.php">home</a> <a href="display.php">display</a> <a href="set.php">set Session</a> <a href="logout.php">Session Out</a>
</body></html>
```

**set.php**

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['name']="Session Set";  ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PHP session</title>
   </head>
   <body>       
       <? if(isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ){ 
       echo "Set a Session :: Session Set";
   } ?>
   <br><br>
       <a href="index.php">home</a> <a href="display.php">display</a> <a href="set.php">set Session</a> <a href="logout.php">Session Out</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add code to this question and clarify what happens and what should happen.

Comment: Have a Session Issues

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Code was always there, it was just an external link. I copied his code, and placed it on his OP for a better question so that future viewers do not have to use the external link.

Comment: @TareqMahmood look at the URL in his external link, for the "Session Out" link

Comment: @CodeGodie, Sorry, my bad!

Comment: @Fred-ii- hows it going.. question.. how do you set the error handler to show that the php tags are missing?

Comment: @CodeGodie good thanks, hope you're the same. *Ah...*, very good question, for one that I don't know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- makes two of us

Answer (score 0):

in your `logout.php` page, you are missing a php open tag `<?php`.

Change this:

```
 <? if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {...
```

to this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {...
```

Comment: your are right but missing only html code in front display code.
php code not missing in backend.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: Sir i have a session create and not ready this session another page without refresh (ctrl+f5).

Comment: Well yeah, you need to refresh the page in order to see that its been destroyed. This does not happen in real time, for that you need some type of web socket or ajax that checks for the session in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think short tag fixes his problem. When i ran your code it works perfectly.
Probably it's configuration issue.

Please read: [How to get my session to write to apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628275/how-to-get-my-session-to-write-to-apache)

see if that fixes your problem for further trouble shooting

I would like to see the phpinfo();

also attach

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
echo session_id(); 
?>
```

to every page I dont think your PHPSESSIONID is not being set. properly

Comment: What is your permission on /tmp/ and does your  user agent has access to that folder? I cant get the session to set at all now.

Comment: Actually that might not be it it works fine with curl

Comment: `curl -c a http://brahmanparivar.com/session/set.php`
`curl -b a http://brahmanparivar.com/session/index.php`
`curl -b a http://brahmanparivar.com/session/display.php`