# SESSION variable array empty

Tags: php, session-variables

Just recently, my logon program failed. The reason is because the SESSION variable return array was empty. This part of my code has been stable for over a year. I asked support on this hosting service, and essentially he said that I was a hack.

I wrote the following short html code to test this (below). I loaded the same code on two additional hosting servers. I was only allowed to link one. All three servers have the session.save_path set to   '/tmp'

This server site works:
[server 1](http://kopay.net/test-session.html)

This server does not:
[server 2](http://ir-advisors.com/test-session.html)

My test codes:

html:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['x']='KOPAY';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST SESSION</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
        <a href='view_session.php'>Show Session Variables</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with its corresponding PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
echo('in php');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: This may be a permissions issue. Try this [other SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628275/how-to-get-my-session-to-write-to-apache)

Comment: or disk might be full on that server

Comment: The hosting service support agreed that it was on their end. I will post when they respond with the fix.